# How to delete item from UI collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, collectionview

I'm new to the collection view in Swift and I'm trying to delete an item from the collection view.

Currently, I have a table-view-like list using collection view (ListVC), and when a user taps an edit navigation bar button, it turns into an edit mode and the user can select one cell.  When an item is selected, I store its indexPath.row in a variable, which I use later when the user edits or deletes an item from the data source, and then present another view controller (ModalVC) to let the user select either delete or edit the item. After the user selects delete or edit the item, I present the table-view-like list with update values.
For instance,

1. the user taps "edit" button in ListVC.
2. the user selects one of the cells in the table-view-like collection view. (ListVC)
3. present ModalVC and let the user taps "delete" button.
4. back to ListVC and display cells with updates (delete the one user selected from the list)

I added SQLite in my project, and I store each item in the database.
So, at first, when the user deletes an item, I just delete one item from the SQLite database and reload the table, get items, and set up the collection view from scratch.

But the problem is every time when the user deletes or edits the item, it reloads the entire table-view-like list (like disappear list a short while and then shows up with a new list).

I read some documents and now I think I should have used deleteItems method for the [NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot). (not really sure though)

I also read the documents and searched for some examples for using deleteItems method in NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot, but I could not find it and feel I'm completely lost now.
If you know how to delete an item from the collection view list without reloading the entire list, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Won't this work in your case?

```swift
removeItemFromSqlite()
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
    collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
}, completion: nil)
```

This will be helpful even if you decide to allow user to select multiple cells, thus having multiple indexPaths to delete